# Way to automate enumerating and inserting subfolders into a command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

Using Robocopy to merge two user home directories shares from two different servers to a new server, but can't use /purge to mirror deletes because it will delete the other servers stuff.

I need a way to enumerate the folder names from the users$ share on each server, and add it to both path statements in the command below, so I can purge at the Users subfolder level.

Robocopy command:

robocopy "\CurrentServer1\users$" "F:\Users" /E /B /COPY:DATSOU /R:1 /W:1 /MT /LOG:"C:\RobocopyLogs\MirrorUsers1.txt"

Can a batch or vbscript do that?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge both source folders into a staging folder, then mirror that staging folder to the destination folder:

```
mkdir C:\staging

robocopy \\server1\src C:\staging /e /b ...
robocopy \\server2\src C:\staging /e /b ...
robocopy C:\staging C:\dst /mir /b ...

rmdir /s /q C:\staging
```